# What did Dumbledore mean when he said,'but I realised' while telling Harry why Dumbledore had left him with Dursleys?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Here is the text from the book:

> 'You might ask-- and with good reason--why it had to be so. Why could some wizarding family not have taken you in? Many would have done so more than gladly, would have been honoured and delighted to raise you as a son.
>
> 'My answer is that my priority was to keep you alive. You were in more danger than perhaps anyone but I realised. Voldemort had been vanquished hours before, but his supporters--and many of them are almost as terrible as he.'

**What did Dumbledore realise?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"but I realised" is not "another thought that's incomplete".  What he's saying here is that only he realized how much danger Harry was in, or put another way, everyone else greatly underestimated the danger to Harry.  The sentence is a little awkward in its construction, and throwing the "perhaps" in there doesn't make it any easier to parse.

"You were in more danger than I realized."  (I underestimated the danger)

"You were in more danger than anyone realized." (Everyone underestimated the danger)

"You were in more danger than anyone but I realized."  (Everyone but me underestimated the danger)

"You were in more danger than perhaps anyone but I realized."  (Everyone but me underestimated the danger, but I'm being humble and allowing that maybe someone else  also knew)

Answer (score 5):

### Dumbledore felt he was the only one to realize how much danger Harry was in

Dumbledore was saying that Harry was in great danger. How great of danger? "more ... than anyone [else than myself] realized". I suspect that you instead parsed it as that Dumbledore was saying "You were in more danger than perhaps anyone" as the first clause and "But I realized" as a second clause, but it's all just one sentence with "but I realized" describing how Dumbledore felt he was the only one (or just about the only one) to realize the danger, everyone else believing everything was tickety boo after Voldemort was defeated.